# Can't change the text content with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I click `option1`, the `showcontent` will show `hello 1`, When I click `option2`, the `showcontent` will show `hi 2`, and more actions.I use JQuery to do this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#option1").click(function() {
    var s = "hello 1";
    $(".showcontent").text(s);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-secondary active">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
</label>
```

However this code can't run, when I click the button, I should not use `$(".option1").click(function(){`, any ideas?

Updates: typo `$(".option1").click(function(){` should be `$("#option1").click(function(){`

Comment: `option1` is an id, not a class.  Also `showcontent` does not exist in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you're attempting to refer to the Options as `.option1` and `.option2`. However, the dot there actually means a class such as if you defined 
`<input type="radio" name="options"`**class**`="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>`

So, replace your `.option1` or whatever with `#option1`. That should fix your problem.

However, the class `.showcontent` doesn't exist within your code. Maybe you would like to add a blank `div` with the class `showcontent`

Answer (score 0):

The event handler doesn't work because you're selecting by class, yet the each radio control has an `id`.

To fix this, and make the code simpler, put a common class on *all* the radio buttons and change their `value` attributes to the text you want to show in `showcontent`. Then you can simply set the `text()` of that element, like this:

```js
$(".option").click(function() {
  $(".showcontent").text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-secondary active">
  <input type="radio" name="options" class="option" autocomplete="off" value="hello 1" checked> Active
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" class="option" autocomplete="off" value="hi 2" /> Radio
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" class="option" autocomplete="off" value="foo 3" /> Radio
</label>

<div class="showcontent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are selecting a `class` not an `id` here: `$(".option1").click(function() {`. but you don't have any element contain class call `.option1`. so try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#option1").click(function() {
    var s = "hello 1";
    $(".showcontent").text(s);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
</label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
</label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
</label>
<div class="showcontent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using on click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".option1").on("click",function() {
    var s = "hello 1";
    $(".showcontent").text(s);
  });
});
```

Also if you want to attach it to the first  option then use its ID in the selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#option1").on("click",function() {
    var s = "hello 1";
    $(".showcontent").text(s);
  });
});
```

Also in html add the following in the html section inside body. This is because you are appending it to element with class `showcontent` on click

```
<div class="showcontent"></div>
```